# Call to a member function save() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the following code

```
public function show()
{

    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $usuario = User::find($id);
    $mascotin = Mascota::all();
    $mascota = Mascota::find($id);
    $mascota->save();

    $cant_mascota = Mascota::count();
    $cant_pregunta = Pregunta::count();

    return view('usuario.show',[
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'mascotin' => $mascotin,
        'mascota' => $mascota,
        'cant_mascota' => $cant_mascota,
        'cant_pregunta' => $cant_pregunta,
    ]);
}
```

It gives me this error

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR).Call to a member function save() on null
```

User Model

```
public function mascotas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Mascota','user_id', 'id');

}
```

Mascota Model

```
public function usuario()
{   
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id','user_id');

}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/home', 'UserController@show')->name('home');
```

Hope you guys can help me, I'm new in laravel and I have like 1 day tring to solve this problem

Comment: `$mascota = Mascota::find($id);` - It did not find any records with the ID, so it returned null. Make sure that `$mascota` is not null before you try to save it.

Comment: _Small Additional Point_ Why would you `->save()` directly after a `::find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$usuario = Auth::user();
$id = $usuario->id; // you already have user from Auth or Request, does not need to request database again
$mascotin = Mascota::all();
$mascota = $mascotin->find($id); // you can search in collection
//if you want to create Mascotin if it doesn't exists use Mascota::firstOrCreate(['id' => $id]);

if(!$mascota){
 throw new \Exception('Mascota not found', 404); //if $mascota is mandatory
}
$mascota->save(); // this does not have place here unless you are changing $mascota before that

$cant_mascota = $mascotin->count();
$cant_pregunta = Pregunta::count();
```

Also you should add auth middleware to this route. Only logged users should see it.
I am not sure what "Mascota" means (it will be good to use english when you share your code) but it is not good to have the same id as user. Better use relationships.

Comment: Mascota = pet, i'm trying to show the pets for X user, but I realize if I don't have any pet in my DB my code is going to fail.

Comment: What is the field name in Mascota table where you store user id? Lets say it is user_id
In your App\User model you can make relation:
public function mascota(){
return $this->hasOne(Mascota::class);
}

Then you use Auth::user()->mascota and you will have the mascota for that user. If it is more than one you should use $this->hasMany().

If the user does not have Mascota, it will return null

Comment: A user has many mascotas but my problem is in the view, mascota is mandatory so it will throw a error because in my view I have a profile for the user and the mascotas he have, but if i don't have a mascota the error willl come@katsarov

Comment: If you are using current user only for the page - just use auth middleware - only logged in user will see the page and his info. It will redirect him to login page when he try to open the page. I am really confused with this non english variables :D